# Preposition Choice with the Word ‘Remix’

Tags: prepositions

The following situation: “A” made a remix of a track that belongs to “B”. Which preposition sounds best to describe it or what would you say most of the time, like in the example sentences?

1. > *A made a remix for the B’s track. / This is an unofficial remix for the B’s track.*
2. > *A made a remix on the B’s track. / This is an unofficial remix on the B’s track.*
3. > *A made a remix of the B’s track. / This is an unofficial remix of the B’s track.*
4. > *A made a remix to the B’s track. / This is an unofficial remix to the B’s track.*

For me, variants from 3 sound very nice. Many people from my country would choose 2, which is obviously a mistake made under the influence of the native language.

Comment: When you say "describe it," what, ***exactly***, is *it*? What's being described? Different prepositions often convey different meanings.

Comment: Being described is a remix of the track, so that both the remix and the track are related to each other as the new version of the song and the original version of the song. I think I cannot be clear enough, sorry for that. What I am interested in is the naturalness of prepositional usage.

Comment: So, track X was made by B. Track Y is a remix of that, made by A. You want to express the action performed by A (rather than, for instance, the location of the result). *Of* would be the most common preposition for that. But you could also simply say *A **remixed** B's track*, which dispenses with prepositions altogether.